# How to deduce $ \mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X}) < \infty \implies\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} (1 - F(x))^2 dx < \infty,~X$ being a non-negative integrable rv?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, integral

> Let $X$ be non-negative random variable and $F$ be its distribution function. Prove the following implications:
> $$
>       \mathbb{E}(X) < \infty \Longrightarrow \mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X}) < \infty \Longrightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} (1 - F(x))^2 dx < \infty
> $$

For the first implication, I prove it as follows:
$$
    \mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X}) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{X} > t)dt = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(x > t^2)dt + \int_1^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t^2)dt
$$
For $t \ge 1, \mathbb{P}(X > t^2) \le \mathbb{P}(X > t)$, thus
$$
    \int_1^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t^2) \le \int_1^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t)dt \le \mathbb{E}(X) < \infty
$$
Now, the second implication is where I'm stuck at. My first attempt is to do the partial integration: Fixed $M > 0$,
$$
    \int_0^M [1 - F(x)]^2 dx = (1 - F(M))\left[M - \int_0^M F(t)dt\right] + \int_0^M \left[x - \int_0^x F(t)dt \right]dF 
$$
But this seems like a dead end. I try to use the tail probabilities to express $\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X})$:
$$
   \mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X}) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{X} > t)dt = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X > u)}{2\sqrt{u}}du
$$
But I still don't have any idea to use this. So, if you have any idea how to show this, I'd love to hear it.

The result has been suggested in [*Stochastic Dynamical Systems with weak contractivity properties*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2265) - Theorem 5.5.

Comment: Are you sure you want to derive the second implication from $E[\sqrt{X}] < \infty$ instead of from $E[X] < \infty$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong This problem actually comes from a paper I'm reading and the theorem in that paper specifically states that "each of the following conditions implies the next one", so I think that it is possible to derive from $\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X}) < \infty$

Comment: I think a reference to your purported result in the paper would be appreciable.

Comment: @User1865345 Ah, sorry. The name of the paper is "Stochastic Dynamical Systems with weak contractivity properties. I. Strong and Local contractivity" and look for Theorem 5.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting problem.  The proof goes as follows: let $X, X_1, X_2$ i.i.d. $\sim F$, then
\begin{align}
 \int_0^\infty (1 - F(x))^2dx = E[\min(X_1, X_2)] \leq E[\sqrt{X_1}\sqrt{X_2}] 
= (E[\sqrt{X}])^2 < \infty. 
\end{align}

By the way, the proof to the first implication is a straightforward application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{align}
E[\sqrt{X}] = E[1 \cdot \sqrt{X}] \leq \sqrt{E[1]E[X]} = \sqrt{E[X]} < \infty. 
\end{align}

Comment: One-liner and yet couldn't be more wittier by incorporating only the minimum and independent characterization. +1.

Comment: (+1) Very slick.